# SqlAlchemy: Check if one object is in any relationship (or_(object.relationship1.contains(otherObject), object.relationship2.contains(otherObject))

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Foo(declarativeBase):
     bars1 = relationship(Bar.Bar, secondary=foos_to_bars1, collection_class=set())
     bars2 = relationship(Bar.Bar, secondary=foos_to_bars2, collection_class=list())
```

(Each of the relationships gives me "Bar"s with a certain conditions). At a certain point, I want to get instances of "Foo"s that have a "bar" (instance of Bar.Bar) in any of the relationships.

If I try to do:

```
def inAnyBar(bar)
   query(Foo).filter(or_(Foo.bars1.contains(bar), Foo.bars2.contains(bar)).all()
```

I get an empty result.

It looks (to me) like I'm doing something like:

```
query(Foo).join(Foo.bars1).filter(Foo.bars1.contains(bar)).\
join(Foo.bars2).filter(Foo.bars1.contains(bar))
```

Since Foo.bars1 doesn't contain bar, the second filter gives empty results.

I've been able to find a workaround with subqueries (each join+filter in a subquery, then or_ all the subqueries) but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it...

I found this:
http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2008/09/09/selecting-booleans/

That does what I want to do, but it's for SqlAlchemy 0.5 and I'm (almost) certain that there's a "cleaner" way to do it with SqlAlchemy 0.6.6

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, `session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.bars1.contains(bar)|Foo.bars2.contains(bar))` produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "Foo".id AS "Foo_id" 
FROM "Foo", foos_to_bars1 AS foos_to_bars1_1, foos_to_bars2 AS foos_to_bars2_1 
WHERE "Foo".id = foos_to_bars1_1.foo AND ? = foos_to_bars1_1.bar OR 
"Foo".id = foos_to_bars2_1.foo AND ? = foos_to_bars2_1.bar
```

which returns incorrect result when one of the `secondary` tables is empty. Seems like a bug in SQLAlchemy. However replacing `contains()` with `any()` fixed the problem (it uses EXISTS subqueries):

```
session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.bars1.any(id=bar.id)|Foo.bars2.any(id=bar.id))
```

Also you can specify OUTER JOIN explicitly:

```
Bar1 = aliased(Bar)
Bar2 = aliased(Bar)
session.query(Foo).outerjoin((Bar1, Foo.bars1)).outerjoin((Bar2, Foo.bars2))\
    .filter((Bar1.id==bar.id)|(Bar2.id==bar.id))
```

Comment: There's not much SQLA can do other than dramatically increase the complexity of the "contains()" operator to use EXISTS when m2m is present, which performs horribly.   any() and has() are nearly useless for this reason.    Feel free to reopen ticket #2177 with a proposal otherwise its closed for now.

Comment: @zzzeek Just using OUTER JOIN is not an option?

Comment: Indeed, it works with session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.bars1.any(id=bar.id)|Foo.bars2.any(id=bar.id)). I'll check the outerjoin version. Thx a lot